# I am getting a different P-Value from statsmodels then SciPy & Scikit-Learn which have the same value

Tags: regression, python, p-value

Any idea why SciPy & SKlearn would produce the same P-Value but not statsmodel sm.ols?

```
DF.columns = ['y','X1','X2','X3','X4',"X5"]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(DF['X2'],DF['y'])
print("Scipy Output:")
print("---------------------------------------------")
print("slope: ",slope)
print("intercept: ", intercept)
print("r_value: ", r_value)
print("p_value: ", p_value)
print("std_err: ", std_err)
print("---------------------------------------------")
test = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=3)
fit = test.fit(DF[['X1','X2','X3','X4',"X5"]],DF['y'])
print("SKLearn Output")
print("p_value: ",fit.pvalues_[1])
print("---------------------------------------------")
model = sm.ols(formula="y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5", data=DF).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

[image: CMD Output]

Comment: Your regressions are different.  `sm.ols` is using all 5 features, but your `linregress` call uses only X2